# Looking for explanation on variable or keyword "code" in extern statement "extern SensLocationStruct code SensLocation[];"

Tags: c, microcontroller, extern

I'm currently figuring out the function and structure of someone else's code, if you have any advice about that it would be appreciated as well.

Anyway, I have come across a word that is included in some extern lines. Here are several lines of code that I have come across.

```
extern unchar code Sdrr[];
extern SensLocationStruct code SensLocation[];
extern SensorConfigStruct code SensorConfig[];
extern unchar code DefaultFruData[];
extern FruLocationStruct code FruDevice[];
```

Now, the word I am talking about is "code".

After sifting through the code, I see no special declaration or definition of the word "code". It does not seem to even been called in a function later on either. It only appears in these extern statements.

The structs are:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char device;
    unsigned char addr;
    unsigned char bus;
} SensLocationStruct;


typedef struct
{
    unsigned char SensNum;
    unsigned char device;
    unsigned char IOType;
    unsigned char regIO;
    unsigned char calib;
} SensorConfigStruct;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char device;
    unsigned char addr;
    unsigned char bus;
    unsigned char frusize;
} FruLocationStruct;
```

Does anyone have any idea of what this is or does? Anything will help.

Comment: Macro probably (#defin). I bet is an attribute to place it in the code segment

Comment: @PeterJ_01 So you're saying somewhere there is a "#define code     " statement, correct?

Comment: @Josh yes, search for `#define code` in all your header files.

Comment: No, that was not it. Is it possible that he used the A51 keyword "code"? Would that even be possible?

Comment: I found a line of code in an .A51 file that reads 'EXTRN CODE (main)' currently seeing where it leads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually used to define the memory space where the variable resides. Intel uses the [von Neumann architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture). There is only one address space, an address like 0x100 clearly identifies the target. On the other hand the [Harvard architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture) have this address twice: In the program **code** memory and in the data memory space. The 8051 family have three memory spaces: ProgramCode, InternalRAM and externalRAM. Each of them requires different instruction for access on assembler level.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot!